# Calling a fragment method from a java class in android

Tags: android

In my java class, I have a context of a `Fragment` now i want to call a function in `Fragment` how is it possible?

```
public JsonParsing(Context context,String data)
{
    this.context=context;// fragment context
    this.data=data;
}
```

Now I want to call a method in a `Fragment` name `setStatus()`

Comment: pass the fragment to constructor as parameter

Comment: iam calling this constructor from fragment and giving a context in arguments

Answer (score 0):

To access non-static methods of your fragment, one solution could be to define a `static` field that holds a reference to the current fragment you're working with:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public static MyFragment currentFragment;

    public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {
        public void setStatus() {
            // TODO set the status
        }
    }

    public void callerMethod() {
        currentFragment.setStatus();
    }
}
```

That way you can access methods of your `MyFragment` instance from any java class that has access to the `MyActivity` class, you can define the `currentFragment` field as private so only the `MyActivity` class or any instance of it can reach your fragment instace.

Also, you can access views inside your fragment by calling `findViewById()` directly from it's parent `Activity` (the one that contains it). Something like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {

        public View onCreate(...) {
            // Inflate a layout that contains a view
            // with the id "view_id".
        }
    }

    public void callerMethod() {
        // Here we access the view that was inside the
        // fragment's layout.
        View view = findViewById(R.id.view_id);
    }
}
```

There would be no problem as long as the fragment was inflated inside (and put in the container of) the `Activity` that looks for the views by the `findViewById` method.

Comment: but why i cant call a method through a context object

Comment: You are using the reference to your fragment that is held by `currentFragment` (which is an instance of the `MyFragment` class) to call the method.